# Postgres select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this question :

> Find the PCs' markers with at least 3 differents speed

using this query:

```
select p.marker,p.type,speed
    from product as p
    join pc  as pc on(p.model = pc.model)
    order by marker,speed
```

I can see the table with all markers, models and their specific speed. But how can I show only the markers with more than 3 speeds? Using this query I can identify which marker has more than 3, but I want the query precisely in the answer.So It'll return just the markers I want

Comment: use `GROPY BY` and `HAVING`

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause will suffice.

If you need the solution for different speeds replace the condition with `count(distinct speed) >= 3`.

```
select p.marker, p.type
from product as p
join as pc on p.model = pc.model
group by 1,2
having count(pc.speed) >= 3
order by 1,2
```

Numbers in group and order by are effectively mapped to columns mentioned within select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to `COUNT()` and then perform `JOIN` like

```
select p.marker,p.type, xxx.speed
    from product as p
    join (select count(distinct speed) as speed, model
          from pc
          group by model
          having count(distinct speed > 3) xxx on p.model = xxx.model
    order by p.marker,xxx.speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want information about a `marker`, then that should be in the `group by` clause -- and nothing else.  The rest is just a `having` clause and the `join` to combine the tables:

```
select p.marker, count(distinct speed) as num_speeds
from product p join
     pc 
     on p.model = pc.model
group by p.marker
having count(distinct speed) >= 3;
```